# Throwing exception from destructor of RAII class

Tags: c++, database, exception, raii

I created a class to encapsulate database transaction to make sure it is either rolled back or committed when an exception is thrown. The problem is that both creating and closing a transaction may fail. Since the transaction is being closed in the destructor, how can I handle a failure without throwing an exception? Obviously if the `TransactionLock` object is being destroyed as a result of an exception being thrown somewhere down the stack, this will result in program termination.

```
// RAII class for database transaction
class TransactionLock {
public:
    TransactionLock(QSqlDatabase& db) :
        m_db(db),       
        m_query(db),
        m_committed(false)
    {
        bool ok = m_query.exec("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION");

        if (!ok)
        {
            throw IOException(m_query.lastError());
        }
    }

    ~TransactionLock() 
    {
        bool ok = m_committed ? m_db.commit() : m_db.rollback();

        // if (!ok) throw?
    }

    void commitTransaction()
    { 
        m_committed = true;
    }       

private:
    QSqlDatabase& m_db; 
    QSqlQuery m_query;
    bool m_committed;   
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never throw in the destructor. Not only because destructor can be called as a result of exception stack unwinding, but also because it is logically senseless.

You can not prevent the object from being destructed, so exception gives you nothing at all. In your particular case, you need to redesign your class. The standard approach is usually to do automatic rollback in the destructor. Commit transaction is an explicit operation with error code.

Comment: But you can throw from a destructor.  There is nothing in the standard that forbids it.  I would not suggest it but it can be done.

Comment: @NathanOliver, this reminds me of an old joke. 'They said I can't run with the ball in my hands when playing soccer, but I just tried - and could do it with no problem!'. You can, but should not.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I've edited the opening line so it isn't quite so over-the-top. The sentiment is correct.

Comment: OK, that's somewhat of an improvement, but `.rollback()` can still fail. Should I just ignore it?

Comment: @jaho, which database are you using? I've worked with multiple, but I've never heard of one where rollback can potentially fail.

Comment: @SergeyA yeah I agree this shouldn't happen. It's a Qt wrapper around sqlite database and the method returns a bool. Reading through sqlite docs now, it seems that in newer versions of sqlite rolling back a transaction will indeed always succeed. I'll just take it for granted. Thanks

Comment: @NathanOliver: There's indeed nothing in the Standard that forbids it, but that's because WG21 couldn't exclude the possibility that there might be a rare case where it made sense. (This happened back in 2002 or so)

Comment: @SergeyA Rollback A Transaction is completely possible to fail, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlendtran-function?view=sql-server-2017 . I think it's the same with other db like MySQL, PostgreSQL, and ORACLE. Many thing such as memory management error, network error, and etc. will cause rollback fail.

Comment: @ASBai in SQL DBs I am familiar with transaction rollback will not cause the data modified inside transaction block to become visible outside of transaction block. So even though it could technically fail in technical sense - server didn't respond to it - it still successful in logical sense, meaning, the data modified during the transaction are not committed.

Comment: @SergeyA So if the database ROLLBACK failed, you will just ignore it, right?

Comment: @ASBai we might alert user that connectivity have failed, but in the end of the day, we know the error is not catastrophic.

Comment: @SergeyA But even if it is not fatal, this type is still not clear how to handle this error correctly. This class of RAII-compliant code should be responsible for the opening and submission of the db transactions only, and it not know how to report this error to the user. So even if you only want to notify the user (for example, a dialog pops up), you still need to pass this exception to the up level.

Comment: @SergeyA Overall, I think if you keep following the RAII guidelines, then you definitely need throw an exception within a destructor. For example: closing a file, releasing a mutex, closing a socket connection, Unmap a file map, closing a communication port, etc. Too much work done in the RAII destruction will fail. What should we do with there failures? In the RAII destructor, we don't have enough information to know how to handle these failures properly. We can only choose to ignore it or pass it to the up level.